# What command does the Visual Studio "Publish Preview" feature run under the hood?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, publish, preview

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.2 app that I deploy to Azure App Service using the "Publish" option in Visual Studio 2017 (after importing the *.PublishSettings file downloaded from the Azure portal).

There's this nice "Preview" feature which allows me to double-check all the changes that will be made on App Service before actually deploying (i.e. get a "diff" / do a "trial run" / do a "what if"). See image below.

**My question:** what command does Visual Studio actually run in the background to achieve this? For reasons I won't go into I'd like to know if this "preview" report can be reproduced on the command line.

[image]

Comment: If you use msbuild you can trigger the same thing by going `msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=True YourSln.sln`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it uses [msdeploy with the `-whatif` flag set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/performing-a-what-if-deployment). An example of such a command may look like this:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync 
-source:package='path.to.zip' 
-dest:auto,ComputerName='...',UserName='$user',Password='pwd',AuthType='Basic' 
-enableRule:AppOffline 
-whatif 
-useCheckSum
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the information I can get, just for your reference:

By using fiddler, when I click the Preview button, I can see it first gets the necessary files from the published azure web app, then I think the visual studio would use something like git to compare the files got from azure with local files. But I cannot get which command are using.

You can raise the issue on msdn of visual studio and azure web app, like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview,visualstudiogeneral&filter=alltypes&brandIgnore=True&sort=relevancedesc&filter=alltypes).